# Finding continuous sequences in Python using Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Given increasing list, my purpose is to return partition of the sequence into subsequences formed by sequential numbers. I want to do it with NumPy. Now, I wish to subtract each time the value of the first element in the relevant part of the list, and ask to the indices where the value in the index equals it's index-- maybe I should modify it , but in the case where the list formed by sequential number, we can see that subtracting the first value gives just list of the indices.

Comment: Will you please show samples of your input list and expected output list?

Comment: Off course :) Let a=[10,11,12,23,30,31,32,204] . Then the expected output is [ [10,11,12], 
 [23], [30,31,32,204] ]

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's pretend your numpy tag is not spurious and you have

```
a = np.array([10, 11, 12, 23, 30, 31, 32, 204])
```

If you apply `np.diff`, you see

```
d = np.diff(a)  # 1, 1, 11, 7, 1, 1, 172
```

Clearly, anywhere that `d` is not `+/-1`, you add a split-point. Using `np.flatnonzero`, you can get indices that are compatible with `np.split`:

```
i = np.flatnonzero(np.abs(d) != 1) + 1  # 3, 4, 7
```

The `+ 1` is necessary because `d` is one element shorter than `a`, being a convolution with `[-1, 1]`.

```
result = np.split(a, i) # [10, 11, 12], [23], [30, 31, 32], [204]
```

Comment: All in all, `np.split(a, np.flatnonzero(np.abs(np.diff(a)) != 1) + 1)`. +1!